# Split Tunnel VPN in Sierra - Keep Getting "route: bad address: ppp0" in Terminal?

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, routing, macos-sierra

I was attempting to split tunnel VPN traffic in Macintosh Sierra using these instructions:

https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/vpn-split-tuenneling/

route add -net XXXXXXX -interface ppp0 add net XXXXXXX: gateway ppp0

I keep getting "route: bad address: add" from terminal with any of the combinations I've tried. how to I determine what to place in the first set of X's and the second set of X's.

Answer (score 0):

You just need `route add -net XXXXXXX -interface ppp0` without the "add net XXXXXXX: gateway ppp0" behind.